# how to compress a bitmap to a lower size image (keeping aspect ratio)

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am just trying to compress a bitmap so I can get a low size image.
like a 2mb image to -100kb but keeping the aspect ratio of the image.

I've tried some of the codes online but it just doesn't work well sometime I even get a bigger image size after compression.
so how can I do this ?!
 but anyways I found this code online:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int path, Canvas canvas) {

    Resources resource = null;
    try {
        final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
        resource = getResources();

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, path, options);

        int scale = 1;
        while ((options.outWidth * options.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale++;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + options.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + options.outHeight);

        Bitmap pic = null;
        if (scale > 1) {
            scale--;
            // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
            // larger than target
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = scale;
            pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, path, options);

            // resize to desired dimensions
            int height = canvas.getHeight();
            int width = canvas.getWidth();
            Log.d("TAG", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

            double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                    / (((double) width) / height));
            double x = (y / height) * width;

            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pic, (int) x, (int) y, true);
            pic.recycle();
            pic = scaledBitmap;

            System.gc();
        } else {
            pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, path);
        }

        Log.d("TAG", "bitmap size - width: " +pic.getWidth() + ", height: " + pic.getHeight());
        return pic;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage(),e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have the image path but I don't know what is canvas (second parameter).
also is there a better way to compress a bitmap?.
  thank you

Comment: It would be far simpler to use `inSampleSize`, as that already maintains your aspect ratio. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Bitmaps/InSampleSize.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) post. Also, to decode a bitmap from path use [BitmapFactory.decodeFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options))